# EJB deployment on Wildfly does not see hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, wildfly

I am trying to deploy an rest service on wildfly 12 and i am using dependency injection provided by the EJB.But when i try to run on server from eclipse i get the following error

```
Class data.FlightManager is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

This is the FlightManagerClass ,i get errors both for the SessionFactory and for the HibernateException,:

```
@Stateless
@Local(IFlightManager.class)
public class FlightManager implements IFlightManager {

    private SessionFactory factory;

    public FlightManager() {
        try {
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public Long addFlight(Flight flight) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Long flightId = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            flightId = (Long) session.save(flight);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return flightId;
    }

    public boolean deleteFlight(Long flightId) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Flight flight = (Flight) session.get(Flight.class, flightId);
            session.delete(flight);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public boolean updateFlight(Flight flight) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(flight);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public List<Flight> getAllFlights() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            flights = (List<Flight>) session.createQuery("FROM Flights").list();
            tx.commit();

            return flights;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return flights;
    }
}
```

and it is injected in the following service:

```
@Stateless
@Local(IService.class)
public class FlightService implements IService<Flight, Long> {

    private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @EJB
    private FlightManager flightManager;

    @Override
    public Long addElement(Flight element) {
        LOGGER.info("addElement called:" + element);

        Long id = flightManager.addFlight(element);

        LOGGER.info("addElement result:" + id);
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteElement(Long id) {
        LOGGER.info("deleteElement called:" + id);

        boolean result = flightManager.deleteFlight(id);

        LOGGER.info("deleteElement result:" + result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Flight updateElement(Flight element) {
        LOGGER.info("updateElement called:" + element);

        boolean result = flightManager.updateFlight(element);

        LOGGER.info("updateElement result:" + result);
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Flight> getElements() {
        LOGGER.info("getElements called");

        List<Flight> flights = flightManager.getAllFlights();

        LOGGER.info("getElements result:" + flights);
        return flights;
    }

}
```

Any ideeas why this is happening ?

Comment: Mostly likely, you are missing the driver dependency for the db. As a side note, since you are not using container-managed transaction, you need to mark your beans with `bean-managed-transaction`

Comment: Are you including Hibernate in your deployment?

Comment: How do i do that? I have the hibernate dependency in gradle